# Window Function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a  with my SELECT statement that I just can't figure out. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  count(1),
  interaction_type_id 
FROM
  tibrptsassure.d_interaction_sub_type
GROUP BY 
  interaction_type_id
HAVING 
  count(interaction_type_id) > 1 
ORDER BY
 count(interaction_type_id) DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

Since my application does not support the use of the LIMIT keyword, I tried changing my query using the `rank()` function like so:

```
SELECT
 interaction_type_id, 
 rank() OVER (PARTITION BY interaction_type_id ORDER BY count(interaction_type_id)
 DESC) 
FROM 
 tibrptsassure.d_interaction_sub_type;
```

However, this way I ended up with the following error message:

```
ERROR:  column "d_interaction_sub_type.interaction_type_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  interaction_type_id, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY inter...    
                    ^
    ********** Error **********

ERROR: column "d_interaction_sub_type.interaction_type_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 9
```

Is there an equivalent of `rownum()` in PostgreSQL? (Apart from using the LIMIT keyword to achieve the same result, that is.)

Does anybody have any suggestions for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean: "My *application* does not support limit"? Programming language, PostgreSql, ORM? Consider providing a SQLFiddle demo, and formatting your SQL commands as source.

Comment: Intelliview Nxt.. The portal which we use to create reports. This doesnt support the limit function.

Comment: But it *does* support *window aggegate functions* (over ... partition by ...)? So you can change the query to using aggregate functions, but not using limit? In other words, what can you use in your query?

Comment: Huh, this looks like really strange question or application behaviour. There is `row_number()` function in postgresql: `select row_number() over()`.

Comment: @TomasGreif, `rownumber` is not quite the same as `rank`. Only the latter can provide a correct ranking in the case when two rows share the same rank.

Comment: @A-B-B: Postgres has a full set of window functions including rank() and dense_rank(): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

Answer (score 1):

Test whether the following works (it is standard postgresql syntax and should work):

```
with 
t as (
   select 1 as id union all 
   select 1 as id union all    
   select 2 union all 
   select 2 union all    
   select 3) 

select 
   id
from
   t
group by
   id
having 
   count(id) > 1
order by 
   id desc
limit 1
```

If this works then you have some syntax problem. If this does not work then you have some other issue - maybe the software you are using is constrained in some really strange way.

You can also use `row_number()`, but it is not very efficient way:

```
with 
t as (
   select 1 as id union all 
   select 1 as id union all    
   select 2 union all 
   select 2 union all    
   select 3) 

, u as (
   select 
      id,
      count(*)
   from
      t
   group by
      id
   )

, v as (
   select
      *,
      row_number() over(order by id) c
   from
      u
   )

select
   *
from
   v
where
   c < 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my query, i.e. there was a syntax error. 
What I needed was the top 5 `category_id` and top 5 instances of `type_id` in each `category_id` and top 5 instances of `sub_type_id` in each `type_id`. To achieve this, I changed the query in the following way and finally got the expected output:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT t1.int_subtype_key, t2.interaction_sub_type_desc, interaction_category_id, 
interaction_type_id, interaction_sub_type_id, count(interaction_sub_type_id) AS
subtype_cnt,
rank()
over (PARTITION BY interaction_category_id, interaction_type_id ORDER BY 
count(interaction_sub_type_id) DESC) AS rank
FROM tibrptsassure.f_cc_call_analysis t1 INNER JOIN
tibrptsassure.d_interaction_sub_type t2 ON t1.int_cat_key = t2.intr_catg_ref_nbr 
AND t1.int_subtype_key = t2.intr_sub_type_ref_nbr INNER JOIN 
tibrptsassure.d_calendar t3 ON t1.interaction_date = t3.calendar_date GROUP BY
t2.interaction_sub_type_desc, t1.int_subtype_key, interaction_category_id, 
interaction_type_id, interaction_sub_type_id) AS sub_type
WHERE rank <= 5;
```

Thanks to everyone for paying attention and helping me with this.

Comment: So basically you surrendered to using a subquery, not that I know of any other way.